# PHPFox Cover Photo

Tags: php, phpfox

I'm using PHPFox Version 3 for a website I dev for. When a user tries to add a cover photo to their profile, it never shows up. I've looked over the code multiple times but can't seem to find anything wrong with it. I may be missing something entirely.

I am relatively new to using PHP so this may have something to do with it. I'll include the code for the cover.html.php file below.

```
<div id="js_cover_photo_iframe_loader_error"></div>
<div id="js_cover_photo_iframe_loader_upload" style="display:none;">{img      theme='ajax/add.gif' class='v_middle'} {phrase var='user.uploading_image'}</div>
<form id="js_activity_feed_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{url link='photo.frame'}" method="post" target="js_cover_photo_iframe_loader">
<div><input type="hidden" name="val[action]" value="upload_photo_via_share" /></div>
<div><input type="hidden" name="val[is_cover_photo]" value="1" /></div>
{if isset($iPageId) && !empty($iPageId)}
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="val[page_id]" value="{$iPageId}" />
    </div>
{/if}
<div class="table">
    <div class="table_left">
        {phrase var='user.select_a_photo'}:
    </div>
    <div class="table_right">
        <div><input type="file" name="image[]" id="global_attachment_photo_file_input" value="" /></div>    
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table_clear">       
    <div><input type="submit" value="{phrase var='user.upload'}" class="button" onclick="$('#js_cover_photo_iframe_loader_error').hide(); $('#js_cover_photo_iframe_loader_upload').show(); $('#js_activity_feed_form').hide();" /></div>
</div>  
<iframe id="js_cover_photo_iframe_loader" name="js_cover_photo_iframe_loader" height="200" width="500" frameborder="1" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

If anyone is able to help, i'd really appreciate it.

Comment: You should check your logs if there are any erros